# Automapper upgrade woes...does not exist in the type

Tags: c#, automapper, typeconverter

I recently did a pretty big upgrade from a much older version of Automapper to the latest.

The upgrade caused a lot of headaches, but the Automapper upgrade guide helped a lot (https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html).

One of the last issues I am dealing with is this:

I changed this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<String, String>()
    .ConvertUsing(Conversion.TrimToNull);
```

To this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<String, String>()
    .ConvertUsing(new Conversion.TrimToNull);
```

Using a class called `Conversion` that looks like this:

```
public static class Conversion
{
    public static String TrimToNull(this String str)
    {
        return str?.Trim().Coalesce(null);
    }
}
```

But now I am getting this error:

```
The name 'TrimToNull' does not exist in the type Conversion
```

I am not sure why it doesn't see `TrimToNull` even though it's in the class.

What could I be doing wrong.  It worked in the older version of Automapper.

Thanks!

Comment: Why did you add "`new`"? `Conversion.TrimToNull` is not a class. You can't allocate a method.

Comment: Conversion is a static class. You would not be calling new on it. So you either need to remove the static keyword, or the new keyword. They're kind of mutually exclusive.

Comment: @madreflection Ah yes. It almost looks like they are trying to use a delegate. I don't know anything about automapper, but I could infer that ConvertUsing is expecting a Func<> or delegate that then calls the TrimToNull function.

Comment: @B.O.B. thanks, I tried changing it to `.ConvertUsing(Conversion.TrimToNull);` and I get `cannot convert from method group to Type` So I am not sure how to get it to recognize it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the auto-mapper guide it seems that they changed the signature from Func<> to Expression<Func<>>. [Auto Mapper Convert Using Update](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html?highlight=convertusing#existing-convertusing-usages)

I believe for that reason you want:

`cfg.CreateMap<String, String>().ConvertUsing(x => Conversion.TrimToNull(x));`

Comment: Hi I tried this and I get a new error that says, `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Type' because it is not a delegate type`

Comment: The expression is missing the parameter: `x => Conversion.TrimToNull(x)`